How can I make the factory class static in factory design pattern?
I was reading an e-book explaining design patterns, and after explaining the factory design pattern, it suggests some improvements. One of them was to make the factory static.

Make the factory (or a factory manager) static: This makes it easier to use but requires additional setup.

But c# doesn't allow inheritance from static classes, so in this case how can I inherit different factories from the main (static) factory class?
For example, if I make a factory BeeFactory as a base class that has a function that returns a product IBee:
public BeeFactory 
{
    public abstract IBee GetBee();
}

And make two subclasses, HoneyBeeFactory and QueenBeeFactory, inheriting from the base class and they have different implementations of what should be done to the product:
public HoneyBeeFactory : BeeFactory 
{
    public override IBee GetBee() 
    {
        IBee bee = new Bee();
        bee.isMakeHoney = true;
        return bee;
    }
}

public QueenBeeFactory : BeeFactory 
{
    public override IBee GetBee() 
    {
        IBee bee = new Bee();
        bee.isMakeHoney = false;
        return bee;
    }
}

So if I made the factory base class static:
public static BeeFactory {...}

The two subclasses would make a compilation error. And if I made the factory class the only factory that exists, how could I have different implementations for the product creation?
It seems to me that making the factory base class static breaks the design itself because I can't inherit from it, so how can I implement the static class concept in the factory pattern? or what does the book refer to?? Thanks in advance.
The book's link (https://unity.com/resources/design-patterns-solid-ebook)

The book (we don't know) might try to show different concepts on getting a factory but did not tell that they aren't meant to be combined. To get somewhere from here (without just telling that using static is almost always a bad starter nowadays) you might want to read about the singelton pattern first. So creating an instance of your factory (maybe that instance stored in a static property but not making the classes static) and making the BeeFactory just an interface then. In the end you should be able to do a QueenBeeFactory.Instance.GetBee(); call then.

Which book is it? What pattern is it? In the most common patterns literature, there's no Factory pattern. GoF, for example, has Abstract Factory and Factory Method, but no Factory pattern.

GoF = Gang of Four we should not torture the next programming generation with decades old acronyms ;)

The book from Unity game engine's resources. https://unity.com/resources/design-patterns-solid-ebook

Just be aware that they present stuff in the context of Unity. That does not mean that you should do it this way in other contextes. Framework often enforce certain derivates of pattern to be used instead of the sometimes most obvious ones. Using multiple factories(or not using a factory manager like stated in the book) and not basing it on Monobehavior like in the book might not be the best ideas in the context of unity. If you actually not targetting Unity you might rather consider different sources to learn about patterns.

What's probably meant is to make each factory Singletons, like this:
public class HoneyBeeFactory : BeeFactory 
{
    public static readonly BeeFactory Instance = new HoneyBeeFactory();

    private HoneyBeeFactory() {}

    public override IBee GetBee() 
    {
        IBee bee = new Bee();
        bee.isMakeHoney = true;
        return bee;
    }
}

Notice that the constructor is private, so that client code can only access BeeFactory via HoneyBeeFactory.Instance.
You can also move common Singletons to the abstract class, if you find that useful:
public abstract class BeeFactory 
{
    public static readonly BeeFactory HoneyBee = HoneyBeeFactory.Instance;
    public static readonly BeeFactory QueenBee = QueenBeeFactory.Instance;

    protected abstract IBee GetBee();
}


Make them public static readonly!

You can't write Beefactory.Instance because Instance is the HoneyBeeFactory attribute.

@MarkSeemann using HoneyBeeFactory.Instance is not easier than using new HoneyBeeFactory .

I do not think that the static members in BeeFactory add much value. I would directly call HoneyBeeFactory.Instance.GetBee() instead of BeeFactory.HoneyBee.GetBee(), or if you want to simplify a little bit, add static methods like GetHoneyBee() there. But even then, you will have two ways to create a bee: Through the specialized classes and through the base class, which might be confusing. KISS Keep It Simple Stupid.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes As I wrote, you can have those members "if you find that useful". In certain scenarios, it can be useful because it may help with discovery. See e.g. the Encoding class for an example of this kind of API design. In other scenarios, it may just be confusing, as you wrote. If such, omit those members. My answer explains what you can do, not what you must do.

@nik0x1 No, HoneyBeeFactory.Instance isn't inherently easier to type than new HoneyBeeFactory(). Did I claim that was the case?

@nik0x1: ... and then the factory wouldn't be a singleton anymore. The point of a singleton is not to make is easier. The point is to ensure only a single instance of a class is created. Compared to a static class, you have the advantage that you can use inheritance, while still having a static access.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes the question contains a quote from a certain book: «This makes it easier to use but requires additional setup». Mark gave the example of a singleton, which does not answer the book's author's claim. This is exactly what I wanted to say in my comment. Singleton doesn't make anything easier.

@MarkSeemann You don't say so, the quote from the question says so: « Make the factory (or a factory manager) static: This makes it easier to use but requires additional setup».

Mark Seemann has your answer as standard approach - when you want to substitute factories, it has to be an instance class because of interface. You can make it singleton, or not - that is depends on situation. If factory construction is expensive, singleton is the better approach, but if cheap - you can make factory facade and create factories as needed.
But now, in the world of Dependency Injection, you can really do different things. For example, .net now allows you to wire objects AsSingleton. Wired this way, class can implement interface and while the class itself is not locked for new construction, calling it from DI GetService guaranteed same instance. Ninjet is a DI framework that allows really fancy object initialization and wiring.
Definitely remember, design patterns are general guidance and not written in stone. You should use it as metal frame but add your own components to it, to satisfy your needs.

You have understood the factory method pattern absolutely correctly.

The factory method pattern deals with interfaces and concrete classes.
We can't inherit from a static class in c# (some thoughts on why this was done - Why can't I inherit static classes?).


P.S. Everything else is the author's fantasy.
P.S. The main idea of ​​a factory method is to make code less coupled (where we did new use factory interface). By making the code less coupled we can, for example, provide a factory implementation in tests that will provide a fake object, without which we would not be able to write a unit test (often we would have to write an integration test with a real object).
